# Getting error "Missing elastic.cluster and elastic.host...." while running indexer job in nutch in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, solr, web-scraping, web-crawler, nutch

I have configured apache nutch 1.13 with solr 5.5.0 and hbase 0.90.6 in eclipse. Now, I am able to run the jobs from injector to invertlinks, but while running indexing job it throws error "Missing elastic.cluster and elastic.host....". I have set indexer-solr under plugin.includes in nutch-site.xml file. But still getting these error. Can anybody help me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the nutch-site.xml. If you see there are two nutch-site.xml; one is under the conf folder and other is in src/test folder. We generally configure nutch-site.xml file under conf folder but when we import it in eclipse, it considers that file under src/test folder. So the way to fix this error is to configure your setting under src/test folder. Generally that file contains very basic config, you need to replace

```
<property>
    <name>plugin.includes</name>
    <value>.*</value>
    <description>Enable all plugins during unit testing.</description>
</property>
```

with below lines

```
<property>
    <name>plugin.includes</name>
    <value>protocol-http|urlfilter-regex|parse-(html|tika)|index-(basic|anchor)|indexer-solr|scoring-opic|urlnormalizer-(pass|regex|basic)</value>
    <description>Regular expression naming plugin directory names to
    include.  Any plugin not matching this expression is excluded.
    In any case you need at least include the nutch-extensionpoints plugin. By
    default Nutch includes crawling just HTML and plain text via HTTP,
    and basic indexing and search plugins. In order to use HTTPS please enable 
    protocol-httpclient, but be aware of possible intermittent problems with the 
    underlying commons-httpclient library. Set parsefilter-naivebayes for classification based focused crawler.
    </description>
</property>
```

So if you want to use solr then use indexer-solr, elastic then indexer-elastic and so on.

Hope this help others.